# How to dynamically adjust panels positions by their size using boostrap

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do some kind of "facebook thingy" and the thing is that I'm making some panels that are side by side of each other (3 in a row), I'm trying to do something similar as google keep notes, that they adjust by their size:

http://cdn.mos.techradar.com/art/other/Onetimers/Google%20Keep%20for%20mobile-970-80.jpg

I found a template that I thought could do the trick, but when using it and modifying it I encounter a problem, the panels behave weirdly, some of the panels adjust but not the others, here is an example of the actual thing:

http://postimg.org/image/pqk735jfv/

I don't know how to achieve this, and I'm kind of lost because I'm new in the Css world, so if some one could guide me that would be great.

here is my html code:

```
<div class="container" id="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="well"> 
         <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <h4>Title</h4>
           <div class="form-group" style="padding:14px;">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="....."></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="button">Post</button>
          <ul class="list-inline">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<!--main-->
<div class="container" id="main">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6">

   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div id="idk" class="panel panel-default">

      <div class="panel-heading"> 
      <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a> 
      <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="//placehold.it/80">
       </a>
      <h4 id="textpost">Edgar Luna</h4>
      <p id="textdown">2 hrs.</p>
      </div> 

        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        </div>

       <div class="panel-body"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x500" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" />
                </div>

          <form>
          <div id="btns" class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default">+1</button><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i></button>
            </div>

          </div>
          </form>

    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div id="idk" class="panel panel-default">

      <div class="panel-heading"> 
      <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a> 
      <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="//placehold.it/80">
       </a>
      <h4 id="textpost">Edgar Luna</h4>
      <p id="textdown">2 hrs.</p>
      </div> 

        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        </div>

       <div class="panel-body"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x500" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" />
                </div>

          <form>
          <div id="btns" class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default">+1</button><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i></button>
            </div>

          </div>
          </form>

    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div id="idk" class="panel panel-default">

      <div class="panel-heading"> 
      <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a> 
      <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="//placehold.it/80">
       </a>
      <h4 id="textpost">Edgar Luna</h4>
      <p id="textdown">2 hrs.</p>
      </div> 

        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. 
        </div>

          <form>
          <div id="btns" class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default">+1</button><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i></button>
            </div>

          </div>
          </form>

    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div id="idk" class="panel panel-default">

      <div class="panel-heading"> 
      <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a> 
      <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="//placehold.it/80">
       </a>
      <h4 id="textpost">Edgar Luna</h4>
      <p id="textdown">2 hrs.</p>
      </div> 

        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        </div>

       <div class="panel-body"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x500" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" />
                </div>

          <form>
          <div id="btns" class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default">+1</button><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i></button>
            </div>

          </div>
          </form>

    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div id="idk" class="panel panel-default">

      <div class="panel-heading"> 
      <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a> 
      <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="//placehold.it/80">
       </a>
      <h4 id="textpost">Edgar Luna</h4>
      <p id="textdown">2 hrs.</p>
      </div> 

        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        </div>

       <div class="panel-body"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x500" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" />
                </div>

          <form>
          <div id="btns" class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default">+1</button><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i></button>
            </div>

          </div>
          </form>

    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div id="idk" class="panel panel-default">

      <div class="panel-heading"> 
      <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a> 
      <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="//placehold.it/80">
       </a>
      <h4 id="textpost">Edgar Luna</h4>
      <p id="textdown">2 hrs.</p>
      </div> 

        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        </div>

       <div class="panel-body"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x500" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" />
                </div>

          <form>
          <div id="btns" class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default">+1</button><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i></button>
            </div>

          </div>
          </form>

    </div>
  </div> 
</div>  
  </div><!--/row-->
 </div><!--/main-->
```

And the CSS (I didnt touch this, because as I said before I don't know a lot of it, just basic things):

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400);
body {
background-color:#e0e0e0;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font: normal 14px Roboto,arial,sans-serif;
}
.navbar-default {background-color:#f4f4f4;margin-top:50px;border-width:0;z-index:5;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a {border:0 solid #4285f4;border-bottom-width:2px;font-weight:800;background-color:transparent;}
.navbar-default .dropdown-menu {background-color:#ffffff;}
.navbar-default .dropdown-menu li > a {padding-left:30px;}

.header {background-color:#ffffff;border-width:0;}
.header .navbar-collapse {background-color:#ffffff;}
.btn,.form-control,.panel,.list-group,.well {border-radius:1px;box-shadow:0 0 0;}
.form-control {border-color:#d7d7d7;}
.btn-primary {border-color:transparent;}
.btn-primary,.label-primary,.list-group-item.active, .list-group-item.active:hover, .list-group-item.active:focus {background-color:#4285f4;}
.btn-plus {background-color:#ffffff;border-width:1px;border-color:#dddddd;box-shadow:1px 1px 0 #999999;border-radius:3px;color:#666666;text-shadow:0 0 1px #bbbbbb;}
.well,.panel {border-color:#d2d2d2;box-shadow:0 1px 0 #cfcfcf;border-radius:3px;}
.btn-success,.label-success,.progress-bar-success{background-color:#65b045;}
.btn-info,.label-info,.progress-bar-info{background-color:#a0c3ff;border-color:#a0c3ff;}
.btn-danger,.label-danger,.progress-bar-danger{background-color:#dd4b39;}
.btn-warning,.label-warning,.progress-bar-warning{background-color:#f4b400;color:#444444;}

hr {border-color:#ececec;}
button {
outline: 0;
}
textarea {
resize: none;
outline: 0; 
}
.panel .btn i,.btn span{
 color:#666666;
}
.panel .panel-heading {
 background-color:#ffffff;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:16px;
 color:#262626;
 border-color:#ffffff;
}
.panel .panel-heading a {
 font-weight:400;
 font-size:11px;
}
.panel .panel-default {
 border-color:#cccccc;
}
.panel .panel-thumbnail {
 padding:0;
}
 .panel .img-circle {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
}
.list-group-item:first-child,.list-group-item:last-child {
 border-radius:0;
}
h3,h4,h5 { 
border:0 solid #efefef; 
border-bottom-width:1px;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
.modal-dialog {
 width: 450px;
}
.modal-footer {
border-width:0;
}
.dropdown-menu {
 background-color:#f4f4f4;
 border-color:#f0f0f0;
 border-radius:0;
 margin-top:-1px;
 }



#subnav {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
#subnav {
 padding-top: 6px;
 }
}

#main {
 padding-top:25px;
}
```

Comment: You can try with this http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Nice! let me check this out!

Comment: it difficult to make with Bootstrap you can use minigrid to customise in your way the way you want
for Exapmle:-> http://alves.im/minigrid/
and add Bootstrap to make panels